# Does $\exp(f(x)) = e^{f(x)}$?

Tags: notation, exponentiation

I've rarely seen the notation $\exp(f(x))$ but whenever I do I just replace it with $e^{f(x)}$. Is this correct, or do these mean something different? Also, in computer science, should these be replaced rather with $2^{f(x)}$ since the base mostly considered is $2$?

Comment: Yes, indeed $\exp(f(x)) = e^{f(x)}$. Regarding the second question, I have not come across the case when $\exp$ is treated as $2$. I would say, unless otherwise stated, treat $\exp$ as $e$.

Comment: Indeed it is almost never the case that $\mathrm{exp}(f(x))\neq e^{f(x)}$. If not otherwise stated, you can assume $\mathrm{exp}(f(x))=e^{f(x)}$.

Comment: $\exp(f(x))$ and $e^{f(x)}$ may or may not be equal, depending on the notational convention. My answers are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4132698/21813) and the bottom of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4460000/21813); also, check out David C. Ullrich's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1392023/21813).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this correct, or do these mean something different?

Yes, it is correct.

And yes, it is different — typographically.  If the exponent gets complicated, typesetting the exponent can result in tiny symbols that might be hard to read.  Using $\exp$ makes the exponent "one level" bigger.  Using notation $e^x$ is preferred, IMHO, for simple exponents because it is shorter and needs less parenthesis.

> Also, in computer science, should these be replaced rather with $2^{f(x)}$ since the base mostly considered is $2$?

No, of course not.  Some math libs provide functions like $\operatorname{exp2}$ and $\operatorname{exp10}$  for bases 2 and 10, respectively, but $\exp$ is still base $e$.

Answer (score 2):

For typographical puroses, when the exponent is complicated, it is preferable to write it with $\exp$ for readability.  Compare
$$
\exp\left(\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) = 
e^{\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}
$$

---

Sometimes in elementary texts we define a function $\exp$, develop some of its properties, and only after a while (from the properties) can we see that it is reasonable to write $e^x$ for this function.